# SQL: How to create a string attribute for relation that matches certain conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a string attribute for a SQL relation (postgreSQL) that must match certain conditions. Specifically, the first 8 characters must be digits i.e.

'0','1', '2',...,'9'

(but the numbers are not INTEGERs/INTs from a TYPE perspective). The 9 character should be a minus sign '-'  and the last four characters should be digits.

Any help (or pointers) is highly appreciated!

Comment: A hourse with no name provided a solution

Comment: Gus -- if his solution meets your needs, you should mark it as correct so future developers with a similar issue will know it was the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have marked it as the correct answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question, but I think you are looking for a check constraint:

```
create table foo 
(
   some_code varchar(13) check (some_code ~ '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}')
);
```

The `~` is the operator that checks for a regular expression in Postgres.

Details about pattern matching can be found in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: Thank, you. I first tried ->      number LIKE '____-%--'     but it was not restrictive enough to just digits.